# limpando/resetando iframe

Tags: iframe

estou trabalhando no projeto de um portal com html5, css3 e js! Quando clico num button, ele carrega o html correspondente para dentro de um iframe.
A questão é: se forem carregadas no iframe os htmls do button "A" e, posteriormente, do button "B", qdo eu volto pelo botão do navegador o iframe vai paginando os htmls do button "B" e em seguida do button "A". 
Eu quero que a cada button pressionado fique carregado no iframe somente os htmls relacionados a esse button!

Alguem tem uma dica pro novato?

abs